# How to set column small in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I can't seem to figure out why col-sm is not working. I have it set to col-sm-6 should should two divs should appear next to each other on smaller screens but it's not working.. Here is my code.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/electronics97188-171025_1508966407077?wid=315&hei=315&qlt=60&fmt=pjpeg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/Sept_Wk5-0930-Video_Games-Nintendo-CB-Consoles143381-180910_1536591280324?wid=315&hei=315&qlt=60&fmt=pjpeg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/toys97188-171025_1508966907610?wid=315&hei=315&qlt=60&fmt=pjpeg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/-06-Scooters196553-191004_1570222568240?wid=315&hei=315&qlt=60&fmt=pjpeg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/Beauty181103-190722_1563828945271?wid=315&hei=315&qlt=60&fmt=pjpeg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <img src="https://target.scene7.com/is/image/Target/HHE171675-190416_1555422913283?wid=315&hei=315&qlt=60&fmt=pjpeg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you explain what "not working" means? What are you seeing? Also, what breakpoints are you targeting for `lg`, `md` and `sm`? I dumped your code into a quick online [sample](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/examples/album/) which uses `768` for `md` and `576` for `sm`, and it shows as three rows of two colums.

Comment: col-sm-6 isn't working. It should show two divs next to each other but it's not doing that. It's simply showing all the divs in one row.

Comment: When you inspect one of the columns with `col-sm-6` set on it, what does your inspector tell you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default,

- `col-*` applies at all widths
- `col-sm-*` applies from `576px` up (and overrides `col-*`)
- `col-md-*` applies from `768px` up (and overrides `col-sm-*` and `col-*`)
- `col-lg-*` applies from `992px` up (and overrides smaller)
- `col-xl-*` applies from `1200px` up (and overrides smaller).

[Relevant documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#grid-options).

Note: the grid breakpoints [can be changed](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#customizing-the-grid) if needed, as well as the number of columns.

---

You seem to expect `col-sm-*` to apply below its breakpoint. For that, replace `col-sm-*` with `col-*`:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-6">
      <img src="..." class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-6">
      <img src="..." class="img-fluid">
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```